# Finding a match in a relation within a query

Tags: parse-platform

I've got a Class Users, which has a relation to a class Containers .
I know an Id for the Container object, and i'm trying to figure out if the user has a specific container as a relation.

My code looks like this:

```
    Parse.User.currentAsync().then((myself) => {

        // create a relation based on the containers key
        var relation = myself.relation('containers');

        // generate a query based on that relation
        var query = relation.query();

        query.equalTo('id', oArgs.container.id);

        query.find().then((found) => {
            if (found.length > 1) {
                deferred.resolve(true);
            } else {
                deferred.resolve(false);
            }
        });

    });
```

I always get an empty set of results.
Can anyone help me understand why, and explain what the correct way is of matching a specific object within a relation?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that using

```
query.equalTo('id', oArgs.container.id);
```

does not work.
Instead I used this:

```
query.equalTo('objectId', oArgs.container.id);
```

And it worked just fine.

Comment: Yes.  The property is called objectId, but the JS SDK accessor is misleadingly called id.  Also note, `query.get(oArgs.container.id)` is equivalent and a little more concise.